# Do I need to put commas on either side of вроде как?

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need to put commas on either side of вроде как?

Foe example:

> Цитата эта, вроде как, к месту.

Comment: No. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on intonation. In principle - no, but if you want to emphasize your uncertainty, make pause, should put commas on either side of this phrase.